# Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot when using Link & Tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I'm using `react-router` for my routing. I have a table and I want the rows to be clickable.

So I have:

```
<table className="table table-hover table-bordered" cellSpacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>GUID</th>
    <th>Patch Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Creation Date</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
{patches.map(function (patch) {
    return (
        <tr className="cursor-pointer">
            <Link to="patch" params={{patchId:patch.id}}>
                <td>{patch.id}</td>
                <td>{patch.guid}</td>
                <td>{patch.name}</td>
                <td>{patch.description}</td>
                <td>{moment(patch.creation_date).format('MMMM Do YYYY')}</td>
            </Link>
        </tr>
    );
})}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Upon clicking a row, I get

> Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(...,
>   .0.2.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.0.1.0.0): Unable to find element. This probably
>   means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually
>   due to forgetting a  when using tables, nesting tags like
>   ,
>
> , or , or using non-SVG elements in an  parent. Try
>   inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``.

If I move `<Link>` to before `<tr>`, i.e:

```
<Link to="patch" params={{patchId:patch.id}}>
    <tr className="cursor-pointer">
        <td>{patch.id}</td>
        <td>{patch.guid}</td>
        <td>{patch.name}</td>
        <td>{patch.description}</td>
        <td>{moment(patch.creation_date).format('MMMM Do YYYY')}</td>
    </tr>
</Link>
```

Then it works fine, but the table CSS is completely messed up. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Link>` renders a `<a>` element, but [a `<tr>` element only accepts `<th>` or `<td>` elements as children](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.5).

The same goes for [`<tbody>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TBODY) and [`<table>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TABLE), which only accept a subset of HTML elements as children.

Your browser will automatically try to fix your HTML. React, unaware of this behaviour, will throw when the DOM structure doesn't match its expectations. As the error points out, this usually happens when outputting an invalid HTML structure in your render method.

If you want your whole `<tr>` to act as a link, you should render a link in each of your table cells.

```js
<tr className="cursor-pointer">
    <td>
        <Link to="patch" params={{patchId:patch.id}}>
            {patch.id}
        </Link>
    </td>
    <td>
        <Link to="patch" params={{patchId:patch.id}}>
            {patch.guid}
        </Link>
    </td>
    {/* etc */}
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Two problems with this: 1. That seems kind of a annoying specially if you have numerous fields. But more importantly, 2. Doing the approach above, will only make the *texts* clickable, and not the row itself. For instance having paddings will generate white space which would now not be clickable.

Comment: Then you need to make it so the surface of your `<a>` elements fills the surface of their parent cell, usually by styling your `<a>` elements as you would style your table cells.